# jquery .appendTo slideshow how to center alt Tag text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have simple jQuery slideshow but I can't work out how to horizontally center align the alt tag text so that when the image doesn't display the alt tag text is centered. I can use text-align: center; which works until the jQuery repeats the slides at which point the alt text becomes left aligned and continues from there on to be left aligned.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#slideshow img:gt(0)').hide();
  setInterval(function() {
    $('#slideshow :first-child')
      .fadeOut(0) // 1000
      .next('img')
      .fadeIn(0)
      .end()
      .appendTo('#slideshow');
  }, 3000);
});
```

```css
#slideshow-wrapper {
    max-width: 476px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto 16px auto;
}

#slideshow {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 80.67226890%;
}

#slideshow img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="slideshow-wrapper">
  <div id="slideshow">
    <img src="images1.png" alt="Alt tag text for image 1">
    <img src="images2.png" alt="Alt tag text for image 2">
    <img src="images3.png" alt="Alt tag text for image 13">
    <img src="images4.png" alt="Alt tag text for image 14">
  </div>
</div>
```

I have continued to try and work this out. Here’s what I have done since posting the question. I have installed Chrome and run the code snippet and indeed it does center the text from the start of the slides and when the jQuery repeats the slides, I also noticed it put some sort of border around the alt text which matched the length of the text and wondered if this is why it works. I have tried adding css directly in the jQuery instead of the style sheet like so:

```
$('#slideshow :first-child').css({'text-align': 'center'})
```

and tried it in different places, but again it only works until the jQuery starts repeating the slides. I have too noticed that having Width and Height values in the img tag can have an effect but it seems it only produces a small square size of text about the first 3 or 4 characters. I have edited this post to include these findings as they be helpful to know in providing a solution that works in IE and Firefox.

How to ceneter the alt tag text in IE and Firefox not just at the start of the slides but also when the jQuery repeats the slides.

Comment: What browser (and version) are you using?  If I hit "Run Code Snippet" in Chrome v64 it keeps the text centered.  Is there something else moving the text?

Comment: I’ve tried all versions to current of Firefox and IE also tried online using codepen and fiddle